# "In-place" EditTextPreference

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I used the XML syntax to create a `PreferenceActivity` with a `PreferenceScreen`. I added an `EditTextPreference` and noticed that this renders as a dialog. Is there a way to make the `EditText` in-place i.e., the text field is displayed right in the `PreferenceScreen` instead of popping up as a dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone comes across the same problem, this cannot be accomplished with the built-in Preference classes, but you can subclass `Preference`, and override `getView()` to return a `ViewGroup` containing an in-line `EditText` (or simply the `EditText` itself).

You could probably achieve this by providing the `android:layout` attribute in the XML too (although I haven't tried this).

**EDIT:**
I tried the `android:layout` approach above, and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

add android:layout="@layout/your_loyout".

where `your_layout.xml` is like

`<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />`